# Does each head in multihead-attention only get a sub-set of the features?

Tags: attention

As far as I've understand, when we have multi-head attention in a layer i.e say 2 heads, then each head gets 1/2 of the features i.e if our embedding size is 512 then each head would get 256 features each.

I get that it is to speed up calculations and being able to compute multiple different "patterns" in parallel etc.. Often I hear that "more heads are better than few" but I can't stop thinking how that is true. I could understand it if all heads get all the features, but if adding more heads reduces the number of features each head can have a look at, then "more is not always better" e.g say we choose 512 heads, then each head would only get 1 feature and I doubt that any of those heads could produces anything that makes sense from only one feature, thus making it a hyper-parameter.

It is often compared to the number of filters in a CNN, but each filter gets all the features in a CNN, thus I don't find that analogy correct.

Am I misunderstanding something here or..?